# Limiting results of foreach

Tags: php

Currently I am scraping a search page and trying to get it to where it only displays 4 results instead of every result on the search page.

My code is here.

```
<?php
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/?s='.$artist.'');
foreach($html->find('div.row > ul > li a') as $element)
{
    //echo 
    $url = ''.$element->href;
    $html2 = file_get_html($url);       
    $image2 = $html2->find('meta[property=og:image]',0);

    // print $image2 = $image2->content;
    $pure = $image2->content;
    $title2 = $html2->find('header.section-header h2 ',0);
    $links = $title2->plaintext;
    // print $title2 = $title2->plaintext;

    print "<li class='album col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-smx-6 col-xs-6 flex' itemprop='itemListElement' itemscope='' itemtype='http://schema.org/MusicAlbum'>
    <meta itemprop='url' content='".$url."'>
    <meta itemprop='numTracks' content='13'>
    <a href='".$url."'>
    <img src='".$pure."' alt='".$links."' title='".$links."' itemprop='thumbnailUrl'>
    <span class='title'><strong class='artist' itemprop='byArtist'>".$links."</strong></span>
    <span class='information'>
    </span>
    </a>
    </li>";
}
?>
```

And this returns something that looks like this.

[image]

But I am trying to get the results to look something more like this.

[image]

Comment: Increase a variable and then use `break` if this variable is equal to 4.

Comment: use for loop and limit your < test expression / condition > till 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your own code, simply use a counter (notice the differences):

```
<?php
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/?s='.$artist.'');
$i = 0; // begin counter 
foreach($html->find('div.row > ul > li a') as $element)
{
    if($i > 3) { // this will ensure that you only display 4 results
        break;
    }
    //echo 
    $url = ''.$element->href;
    $html2 = file_get_html($url);       
    $image2 = $html2->find('meta[property=og:image]',0);

    // print $image2 = $image2->content;
    $pure = $image2->content;
    $title2 = $html2->find('header.section-header h2 ',0);
    $links = $title2->plaintext;
    // print $title2 = $title2->plaintext;

    print "<li class='album col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-smx-6 col-xs-6 flex' itemprop='itemListElement' itemscope='' itemtype='http://schema.org/MusicAlbum'>
    <meta itemprop='url' content='".$url."'>
    <meta itemprop='numTracks' content='13'>
    <a href='".$url."'>
    <img src='".$pure."' alt='".$links."' title='".$links."' itemprop='thumbnailUrl'>
    <span class='title'><strong class='artist' itemprop='byArtist'>".$links."</strong></span>
    <span class='information'>
    </span>
    </a>
    </li>";
    $i++; // increment your counter
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Start a counter before your loop

```
$i=1;
```

Then increment it after every iteration

```
$i++;
```

Then check if it has reached 4 and break

```
$i=1;
foreach($test as $value)
{
   if($i>4) 
     break;
   //rest of your code here
   $i++;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/504915)**

And Nope, i will not update this answer with your code because that will not be a learning experience for you. It will then just become a copy paste job which doesn't help you in the long run. Just go over it a couple of times then apply this simple solution to your code and you will never forget it :)

Comment: I've posted a similar answer that uses your code, check it out.

Comment: It wasn't to copy and paste... I was not sure where to put the code you displayed above. - You said "//rest of your code here".

Comment: Ah ok then the confusion resulted from my comment sorry for that. Since you have got another answer i think it will be redundant to update it now

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Yea! Thank you also buddy!